# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when assigning string

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to assign string passed from java application via jni to field of c++ class instance but keep getting error which seems to come from nowhere. My application crashes in native code which does nothing but assighment.

JNI method in which crash occures

```
[SCVXManager.java]

public static native void configure(String server, String realm, String username, String accountHandle);

[SCVXManager.cpp]

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_mods_voicechat_SCVXManager_configure(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass jcl, jstring server,
                                                                 jstring realm, jstring username, jstring accountHandle) {

    auto app = SCVXApp::getApp();

    auto serverStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(server, NULL);
    auto realmStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(realm, NULL);
    auto usernameStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(username, NULL);
    auto accountHandleStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(accountHandle, NULL);

    app->configure(serverStr, realmStr, usernameStr, accountHandleStr);

    jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(server, serverStr);
    jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(realm, realmStr);
    jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(username, usernameStr);
    jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(accountHandle, accountHandleStr);
}
```

Definition of native method in which crash occures and related variables.

```
[SCVXApp.cpp]

void SCVXApp::configure(const string &server, const string &realm, const string &username, const string &accountHandle) {
    m_server = server;
    m_realm = realm;
    m_username = username;
    m_accountHandle = accountHandle;
}

[SCVXApp.h]

class SCVXApp {

private:
    string m_realm;
    string m_server;
    string m_accountHandle;
    string m_username;

    <...>
}
```

Crash stacktrace

```
Current thread (0x00000000050d5800):  JavaThread "Main thread" [_thread_in_native, id=22916, stack(0x0000000004ed0000,0x0000000004fd0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00007ffbf2a6cb64

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000cccccccc, RBX=0x000000003e7e69d8, RCX=0x00007ffbf2a6cb64, RDX=0x000000002614e2e0
RSP=0x0000000004fcce58, RBP=0x0000000004fcd0f0, RSI=0x00000000c1720228, RDI=0x0000000004fcce80
R8 =0x0000000000000020, R9 =0x0000000004fccfd0, R10=0x000000002614e2e0, R11=0x00007ffbf2a6cb64
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000003e7e69d8, R14=0x0000000004fcd128, R15=0x00000000050d5800
RIP=0x00007ffbf2a316e9, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000004fcce58)
0x0000000004fcce58:   00007ffbf2a6594c cccccccccccccccc
0x0000000004fcce68:   cccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccc
0x0000000004fcce78:   cccccccccccccccc 0000000004fcced0
0x0000000004fcce88:   00007ffbf2a65578 00007ffbf2a6cb64
0x0000000004fcce98:   000000002614e2e0 0000000000000020
0x0000000004fccea8:   cccccccccccccccc 0000000004fccf40
0x0000000004fcceb8:   00007ffbf2a6cb64 cccccccccccccccc
0x0000000004fccec8:   cccccccccccccccc 0000000004fccf10
0x0000000004fcced8:   00007ffbf2a697da 0000000004fccf40
0x0000000004fccee8:   000000002614e2e0 0000000000000020
0x0000000004fccef8:   cccccccccccccccc 0000000004fcd020
0x0000000004fccf08:   cccccccccccccccc 0000000004fccf40
0x0000000004fccf18:   00007ffbf2a67905 0000000004fccf40
0x0000000004fccf28:   0000000004fcd020 cccccccccccccccc
0x0000000004fccf38:   cccccccccccccccc 0000000004fcd060
0x0000000004fccf48:   00007ffbf2a6cb64 0000000004fccec0 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ffbf2a316e9)
0x00007ffbf2a316c9:   8b df 48 8b f9 49 8b c8 4c 8b c6 49 8b f2 f3 a4
0x00007ffbf2a316d9:   49 8b f0 49 8b fb c3 0f 10 02 41 0f 10 4c 10 f0
0x00007ffbf2a316e9:   0f 11 01 41 0f 11 4c 08 f0 48 8b c1 c3 66 66 0f
0x00007ffbf2a316f9:   1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b c1 4c 8d 0d f6 e8 ff 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x0000000004ed0000,0x0000000004fd0000],  sp=0x0000000004fcce58,  free space=1011k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [VCRUNTIME140D.dll+0x16e9]
C  [vivox_test.dll+0x594c]  std::char_traits<char>::move+0x3c
C  [vivox_test.dll+0x5578]  std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign+0x78
C  [vivox_test.dll+0x97da]  std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::operator=+0x8a
C  [vivox_test.dll+0x7905]  SCVXApp::configure+0x45
C  [vivox_test.dll+0xcb64]  Java_net_core_processing_SCVXManager_configure+0x134
C  0x00000000051f09cc

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  net.core.processing.SCVXManager.configure(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
j  net.core.processing.SCVXController.load(Lnet/common/event/InitializationEvent;)V+39
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
<...>
```

It's might be important to note that none of the fields which are assigned in `configure` function are not referenced anywhere else before that.

If that matters `vivox_test.dll` is my shared library built with MSBuild using CMake

I dont understand what causing this issue and how can I solve this.

Comment: _"which does nothing but assignment"_ -- so show the declarations of `m_server`, `m_realm`, etc.

Comment: @JimGarrison Updated the question and added piece of header file.

Comment: Well, have you positively determined that instruction pointer `0x00007ffbf2a316e9` is in `SCVXApp::configure`?  Could `SCVXApp::getApp()` have returned an invalid pointer?  Please do more debugging on your own before posting here, and if you've done all this then make it clear in your question.  There really isn't enough information in your question for anybody to help you here.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use move semantics. (Remove "&" from 4 arguments, leave just "string" in C++ function). Use copy. Probably move-related issues with string returned from jenv. Also, check (debug) your strings returned from jenv.

Comment: std::char_traits<char>::move+0x3c
Exception in move.

Comment: the compiler may have decided to use a move but that isn't the problem, GetStringUTFChars returns a raw character pointer so the string being moved from must have been created as a temporary when calling configure

Comment: may be the case. But crash is in move. If it will be in copy, then we know for sure issue is with initial data. So I wrote another statement about debugging (at least logging). Maybe his app is null, too.

Comment: but if you remove the references the compiler is even more likely to generate a move as it knows for sure the temporaries aren't going to be used again. Far more likely is that app is null/invalid/corrupted

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, you're right. Pointer to app was corrupted somehow. Fixed it and now it seems to works. Thanks for the hint!